# How to find the error displayed on my project.?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing the code in eclipse. In my project explorer there is an error(red x mark) displayed on my project name. But there are no errors in the other sub folders.Can any one say where can i find those errors.? What is to be done to find the problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The errors from Eclipse are usually avaiable from  Error Log View

Window -> Show View -> Erro Log View

Also you can try to clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause for such thing is *build path* issues. Go to your project build path and look at the list of included jars: check if you have any jar marked with the same red x. Also, check the eclipse "Problems" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 'Problems' tab (hit Ctrl-3, then start typing Problems). It will give a description of what's wrong.